# how to show the draws in count using mysql?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am making a voting system in visual basic, I'm struggling to write the right query for identifying the max vote count and also showing the the same vote count, what I mean is the draw in the candidates, how can I identify if there are draws in the election... here is my code

```
Private Sub president()
    Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand("SELECT MAX(VOTECOUNT) as MV FROM candidates WHERE POSITION = 'PRESIDENT'", con)
    Dim rd1 As MySqlDataReader
    con.Open()
    rd1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
    If rd1.Read() Then
        MV = rd1("MV").ToString
    End If
    con.Close()
    rd1.Dispose()
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT CONCAT(FIRSTNAME,' ',MIDDLENAME,' ',LASTNAME) AS FULLNAME,POSITION, VOTECOUNT FROM candidates WHERE POSITION = 'PRESIDENT' AND VOTECOUNT = '" & MV & "'", con)
    Dim rd As MySqlDataReader
    con.Open()
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While rd.Read()
        TextBox1.Text = (rd("FULLNAME"))
    End While
    rd.Close()
    con.Close()
```

Comment: At each loop in the final while you rewrite the content of the textbox with the current record overwriting whatever you have found in the previous record. I suggest to use a multiline textcontrol and then use the method AppendText instead of writing directly to Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Using...End Using` blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed. You can use `.ExecuteScalar` to get a single value from the database. This returns an `Object` so a `CInt` is needed. I think one of your problems was that you were surrounding `MV` in single quotes in the second Select statement. I am sure that this is an Integer and you were passing it as a string. Using parameters solves this problem.

```
Private Sub president()
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(ConStr),
        cmd1 As New MySqlCommand("SELECT MAX(VOTECOUNT) as MV FROM candidates WHERE POSITION = 'PRESIDENT'", con)
        con.Open()
        Dim MV = CInt(cmd1.ExecuteScalar())
        cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT CONCAT(FIRSTNAME,' ',MIDDLENAME,' ',LASTNAME) AS FULLNAME,POSITION, VOTECOUNT FROM candidates WHERE POSITION = 'PRESIDENT' AND VOTECOUNT = @MV"
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@MV", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = MV
        Using rd = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
            While rd.Read()
                TextBox1.AppendText(rd("FULLNAME").ToString & vbCrLf)
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```